# how to load different data tables in different tabs?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

i am using laravel data tables to generate different data table on different tabs. but it runs only query of first data table rendered to the page.i already have attached scope to data table to generate different results for different condition

i have attached ajax() method to the data table that are not displayed in the beginning of the page

controller file

```
public function index(UpcomingReservationDataTable $UpcomingReservationDataTable)
    {
        return $UpcomingReservationDataTable->render('admin.reservations.index');
    }

public function getAllReservationTable(ReservationDataTable $ReservationDataTable){
        return $ReservationDataTable->render('admin.reservations.index');
    }

    public function getPastReservationDataTable(PastReservationDataTable $PastReservationDataTable){
        return $PastReservationDataTable->addScope(new PastReservationScope)->render('admin.reservations.index');
    }
```

pastreservationdatatable query

```
public function query(Reservation $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->where('pickup_date','<',date('Y-m-d'))->orderBy('id','desc')->with('customer','package','vehicle');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show first table in load tab and next change it by ajax.

Comment: that's exactly what did but the different query does not run when different tabs are opened.

Answer (score 0):

You must write a function in javascript. This function should take a value. This value contains your query information. When this is clicked on any tab, this function must be executed with that value. The function of this function is to send information to the server, receive and display. Did you do these things?
The next issue is when the Ajax data is sent, if the server path is wrong, you will encounter an error. To view errors on your browser, press the combination keys CTR + Shift + i[image] and in the menu at the top of the window, select the console to display the errors.

Comment: wrote the javascript function as defined in documentation. The problem was in web.php file. when you put path similar to resources routes after the path will get conflicted and generate different result. so, it was best to put the route before the resources path